# Digital Asset Management Web application

Tags: windows, web-apps, file-management

I am looking for a digital asset management web application software. We are planning to host it on our own.

- Must run on Windows (IIS or Apache)
- Should be developed in ASP.NET or PHP
- Must have a template system or workflow to completely adapt to a HTML5 responsive design
- Must support these types of assets: Video files (preview and player), images (EPS including conversion to a pixel format, JPEG, PNG, GIF - thumbnails for all these formats), documents (PDF)
- Can be open or closed source
- Must have Batch upload capability (to upload mutliple files at once)

Comment: Was this question too difficult?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be too late but I can give several suggestions here:

#### Open Source

- [Resourcespace](http://www.resourcespace.org/) is pretty easy to use and is written in PHP. It runs on any platform. Pretty easy to use and setup.

#### Commercial

- **High-End**
  [ADAM Software](http://www.adamsoftware.net/) might be a good .NET based solution that will do alot more than what you are looking for and it will cost you a ton.
- **Mid-level**
  [Elvis DAM](http://www.cyangate.com/products/elvis-dam/) is based on Java but has the best user interface and it is effordable based on number of users, assets, etc.
- **Low-level**
  [Asset Bank](https://www.assetbank.co.uk/) is almost like a photo gallery but pretty practical and provides the base DAM functions.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at [razuna](http://razuna.org/)?

It is written in JAVA, but comes in an easy-install all-in-one zip (including a fully configured tomcat servlet container) and according to documentation runs on windows (I only tried it on Linux).

- Drag'n'drop uploads, multiple file uploads, import from URLs, import
  from Filesystem, ...
- All mentioned asset types and then dozens of other types
- File Conversion, including postscript files via ghostscript, video via ffmpeg
- Video player

It should fulfill all your requirements, except maybe number three. 
I don't really understand what you mean by that - do you want to use it from a smartphone? That probably wont work (in a satisfactory way) unless you take to GUI modifications - it's an open source system, or you could ask the makers for a custom smartphone GUI.

Comment: Yes it should be usable on devices like smartphones. I think I am going to test it. Thank you. I would prefer a solution that is written in C#.